# What value is returned when a method exits early on a return keyword with no argument?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following Ruby method:

```
def increment(value)
    return if value >= 999
    
    value + 1
end
```

What value gets returned to the caller from this method if the `return` statement executes?

From running this code myself, it appears that `nil` is returned. But is it always guaranteed to be the case that a `return` with no argument specified implicitly returns `nil`? Is this behavior documented somewhere? Is the behavior Ruby language version-dependent?

I checked several of the various sites linked to from https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/, including http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/, without locating a definitive answer.

Comment: Related, but doesn't provide an authoritative source: https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide/issues/557

Comment: An easier test: `def test; return; end; test.nil? #=> true`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return` is a [Ruby keyword](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/keywords_rdoc.html). From the documentation:

> **return** Exits a method. See [methods](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/methods_rdoc.html). If met in top-level scope, immediately stops interpretation of the current file.

From the [return values](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values) section of the methods documentation:

> By default, a method returns the last expression that was evaluated in the body of the method. ... The return keyword can be used to make it explicit that a method returns a value.

From [*The Ruby Programming Language*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/) by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto (creator of the Ruby programming language), **chapter 5.5.1 return**:

> `return` may optionally be followed by an expression, or a comma-separated list of expressions. **If there is no expression, then the return value of the method is `nil`.** If there is one expression, then the value of that expression becomes the return value of the method. If there is more than one expression after the `return` keyword, then the return value of the method is an array containing the values of those expressions.

This last passage can be considered the canonical answer, though I believe there may be additional information in [ISO/IEC 30170](https://www.iso.org/standard/59579.html) on this.

To clarify how using `if` as a modifier is evaluated by the interpreter in your example, I'll again quote *The Ruby Programming Language*, **chapter 5.1.2 if As a Modifier**:

> When `if` is used in its normal statement form, Ruby’s grammar requires that it be terminated with the `end` keyword. For simple, single-line conditionals, this is somewhat awkward. This is just a parsing problem, and the solution is to use the `if` keyword itself as the delimiter that separates the code to be executed from the conditional expression. Instead of writing:
>
> `if expression then code end`
>
> we can simply write:
>
> `code if expression`
>
> When used in this form, `if` is known as a statement (or expression) modifier. If you’re a Perl programmer, you may be accustomed to this syntax. If not, please note that the code to execute comes first, and the expression follows. For example:
>
> `puts message if message # Output message, if it is defined`
>
> This syntax places more emphasis on the code to be executed, and less emphasis on the condition under which it will be executed. Using this syntax can make your code more readable when the condition is a trivial one or when the condition is almost always true.
>
> Even though the condition is written last, it is evaluated first. If it evaluates to anything other than `false` or `nil`, then the code is evaluated, and its value is used as the return value of the modified expression. Otherwise, the code is not executed, and the return value of the modified expression is `nil`. Obviously, this syntax does not allow any kind of `else` clause.

Answer (score 3):

According to [ISO/IEC 30170](https://www.iso.org/standard/59579.html), the `return` expression works like this: (the right-hand side being the returned value)

```rb
return          #=> nil
return obj      #=> obj
return a, b, c  #=> [a, b, c]
```

Then there is `return *obj` which works like the splat operator in [method calls](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion), i.e. it converts `obj` to an *argument list* and returns that list as an array:

```
return *1..5  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The standard notes that if the resulting argument list has a size of 1 or 0, the return value is implementation-defined. So it *could* work like this:

```rb
return *[]      #=> nil
return *[a]     #=> a
return *[a, b]  #=> [a, b]
```

However, the Ruby implementations I know always return an array when using `*`:

```rb
return *[]      #=> []
return *[a]     #=> [a]
return *[a, b]  #=> [a, b]
```

Outside of a method invocation, `return` raises a [`LocalJumpError`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/LocalJumpError.html) with a `reason` value of `:return` and an `exit_value` corresponding to the return value as described above.

You can find more examples and edge cases in the the Ruby Spec's [language/return_spec.rb](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/return_spec.rb) which also contains a test for a blank `return`:

```rb
  it "returns nil by default" do
    def r; return; end
    r().should be_nil
  end
```